# How to capture dynamic button clicks in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

I have created a bunch of buttons by binding an ObservableCollection<module>.

In my ViewModel I would like to capture the click event.

For buttons I usually use:

```
RelayCommand launchCommand;

public ICommand LaunchCommand{
    get{
        if (launchCommand == null){
            launchCommand = new RelayCommand(LaunchCommandExecute, CanLaunchCommandExecute);
        }
        return launchCommand;
    }
}

private void LaunchCommandExecute(object parameter){
    //Do something to recognize the button.
    //Could use ObservableCollection<Module> module_objects
    //to match, if I could get the buttons content or name
}

private bool CanLaunchCommandExecute(object parameter){
    return true;
}
```

In LaunchCommandExecute I have placed a couple of thoughts. I would be interested in what object parameter holds? Is it anything useful to me?

The button has the following bindings which I could use to match up:

```
<Button Tag="{Binding ModuleName}" Content="{Binding ModuleAbbreviation}" Command="{Binding LaunchCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding ModuleDisabled}" Style="{DynamicResource LauncherButton}" Background="{Binding ModuleColor}" />
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

**[EDIT]** This is after accepting the answer below

What I am finding is that LaunchCommand is not firing. I was wondering if anything in the below code is conflicting?

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:LauncherViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static m:ModuleKey._module_objects}}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <my:AlignableWrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="alignableWrapPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <Button Content="{Binding ModuleAbbreviation}" Command="{Binding LaunchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ModuleName}" IsEnabled="{Binding ModuleDisabled}" Style="{DynamicResource LauncherButton}" Background="{Binding ModuleColor}" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Tahoma" Width="130" Height="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

**[EDIT Answer]** Nevermind thought about what I was trying to do and found that the command could not see the correct DataContext. Adding the following sorted it:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.LaunchCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parameter` is set by `CommandParameter`.  In this case, all you have to do is bind it to "ModuleName":

```
<Button Command="{Binding LaunchCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ModuleName}" ...
```

Pick it up using a cast - assuming it's a string:

```
private void LaunchCommandExecute(object parameter){
    string moduleName = parameter as string;
    // ...
}
```

(Note that you could also set `CommandParameter` to the Button's Tag or Content by using `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Tag}`, but that would be a round-about approach in this case.)

Comment: Strangely I am finding my LaunchCommand is not firing. I made an EDIT including the XAML. Can you see anything peculiar?